# Angular 4 ng serve takes more than 5 minutes

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

My problem is that when I run `ng serve --source-map false` or `ng serve`. Its takes around 5-7 minutes to get code compiled after changes have been made.

Angular version 4.4.7 and other detail is as listed below:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.10.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 4.4.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: my initial question is how big is your project, second why not upgrade to angular 6?

Comment: Did you consider implementing lazy loading ? How powerful is your computer ?

Comment: yes we have implemented lazy loading and we have around 80-90 modules.

Comment: not really a solution but in my case it help if you delete node modules and re install dependencies

Comment: System detail: 8gb ram, intel i5 7th gen

Comment: What are your computer specs? does the same thing happen on another computer??

Comment: @SmokeyDawson , windows 10, 8gb ram, intel i5 7th gen, yes same thing happens on another computer as well.

Comment: @gudboisgn Were you able to solve this?